# Open context menu by clicking on menu options item

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu

I use Android to make an application.
I have an activity where I create an option menu like below

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The menu is loaded from an xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <item android:title="Item1" android:id="@+id/item1" /></menu>
```

When I click on item 1, I use onOptionsItemSelected on my activity to work after the click like that :

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1 :
        // here, I would like to open a contextual menu
        return true;
    default :
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So, when user click on item 1 I would like to open a contextual menu. First, I don't know if it's possible to open a contextual menu directly without using hold position on screen like several tutorials on internet show it.

If it's possible how can I open a contextual menu in that way ?

I thought to use `registerForContextMenu()` and `openContextMenu()` in the case of my item 1 but which view should I put in parameter ?

If someone has an idea about the way to make that, I would like to know how I must do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to have a contextual menu, then I'd use the contextual menu as it is designed in Android by doing a long-press on a given item. People are accustomed to this and apps shouldn't differ in that.

The alternativ is a bit more complex. What you could do is to have your menu loaded in a separate activity which you style as a dialog window (you know with a faded half-transparent background). This can be easily done by applying the `Theme.Dialog` style to your activity in the manifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.TagPopupActivity"
            android:label="Tagging" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
                ...
</activity>
```

Alternatively you can also directly create a Dialog window as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html). You then get the context (i.e. a list click) by implementing the appropriate click listener in your main list activity and then when the user clicks on the item, you retrieve its id and package it into a bundle that you forward to your "menu"-activity styled as a popup dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

In fact, I begin with Android. So i don't know very well what is the best practice to make things.

In my head, there were 2 possibilities. First, I created a contextual menu but apparently it's not a good idea for the user experience.

Second, I thought to launch new activity by clicking on item in which I display the choice that I wanted to propose to users in the context menu. Perhaps it's a better idea. 

So, I think that I'm going to code the second idea.

Comment: Even Google's own apps open Context Menus from Menu Items, so I don't think would rule that long-presses are the proper way to implement it.

Comment: Where is the answer for `Open context menu by clicking on menu options item`?

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is old but here's another solution (quick but not really sexy).

Add a fictive view with the visibility set to gone and use this view to trigger the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final int OPTION_1 = 21;
private final int OPTION_2 = 22;    

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    ActionMenuItemView btn = findViewById(item.getItemId());

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_share:
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, btn);
            popupMenu.getMenu().add(0, OPTION_1, 0, "Option 1");
            popupMenu.getMenu().add(0, OPTION_2, 0, "Option 2");
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this::onClickMenu);
            popupMenu.show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private boolean onClickMenu(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case OPTION_1:
            // Clicked option 1
            break;
        case OPTION_2:
            // Clicked option 2
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```